# Proving multiplicaiton and addition closure from inequalities

Tags: calculus, logic, arithmetic

I have been studying Spivak's Calculus book. It has been a long time since I've done any math, so I thought I would start slowly from the Prologue. The book states the following properties (just the basics, don't worry too much about them):

$$
\begin{equation}
a + (b+c) = (a+b) + c \\
a + 0 = 0 + a = a \\
a + (-a) = (-a) + a = 0 \\
a + b = b + a \\
a \cdot (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c \\
a \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot a = a \\
a \cdot a^{-1} = a^{-1} \cdot a = 1 \\
a \cdot b = b \cdot a \\
a \cdot (b + c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c \\
\end{equation}
$$

He then defines the following three properties, which in a later exercise he wants to derive them as theorems, using a different set of axioms instead.

P10: For every number $a$, one and only one of the following holds (where $P$ is the set of positive numbers):

1. $a = 0$
2. $a \in P$
3. $-a \in P$

P11: If $a \in P$ and $b \in P$, then $a + b \in P$

P12: If $a \in P$ and $b \in P$, then $a \cdot b \in P$

In exercise 8 states that properties P10-P12 can be derived from the following 4 properties instead:

P'10: For any numbers $a$ and $b$ one, and only one of the following holds:

1. $a = b$
2. $a \lt b$
3. $b \lt a$

P'11: For any numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, if $a < b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$.

P'12: For any numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, if $a < b$, then $a + c < b + c$

P'13 For any numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, if $a < b$ and $0 < c$, then $a \cdot c < b \cdot c$.

With all that out of the way. I was able to prove the original P10 rather trivially, so let's skip that. However, I my proofs for P11 and P12 may have a bad assumption somewhere. The problem is, in all my proofs, I never used the property P'12. From the wording in the problem, I would expect all the properties are required.

All proofs here will make use of the definition $a < b \implies b - a \in P$. My proofs are:

P11: From P'11, if $b - a \in P$ and $c - b \in P$, then $c - a \in P$. Let $b = 0$. We have: if $0 - a \in P$ and $c - 0 \in P$ then $c - a \in P$. From there, simple variable substitution, $a' = -a$ and $b' = c$, we have exactly what we want: $a' \in P$ and $b' \in P$ then $b' + a' \in P$. Obviously we can use the commutative property to get it exactly where we want it.

P12: From P'13, if $b - a \in P$ and $c - 0 \in P$, then $b \cdot c - a \cdot c \in P$. For that one, using the distributive property we have: if $b - a \in P$ and $c \in P$, then $(b - a) \cdot c \in P$. There again, just a simple variable substitution ($a' = b - a$ and $b' = c$) will get us where we want.

Unfortunately, the book doesn't have the solution for the problem, so I'm resorting to the powers of the Internet to help me out here. If you don't want to try to understand my proof but can just give me a proof that uses all the axioms, it may already be of help to me. Right now I'm kinda stuck finding alternative solutions.

Comment: But $P'12$ follows from your definition of $a\lt b$. Namely we have $$a\lt b\iff b-a\in P\iff (b+c)-(a+c)\in P\iff a+c\lt b+c$$ so it's hardly an axiom.

Comment: yes, you are right, maybe what I did is fine in the spirit of the exercise.